# Python: is there a module to mesure CPU usage over time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have Python program which uses multiprocess module. I am trying to to check how to memory and process it uses over a time.

for checking memory I am using **memory_profiler** and it works perfectly fine. it gives me exactly what I want, a graph of memory usage over time.

is there any module I could try to check the **CPU usage** in similar fas

Answer (score 2):

The psutil library is able to give system information (CPU / Memory usage)

> psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information on running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many functionalities offered by tools like ps, top and Windows task manager.
>
> It currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX, Sun Solaris, FreeBSD,
>   OpenBSD and NetBSD, both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, with Python
>   versions from 2.6 to 3.5 (users of Python 2.4 and 2.5 may use 2.1.3
>   version).

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil